# Multiple Items into one pipeline -- NEO4J database with scrapy use case

Tags: python, neo4j, scrapy, pipeline, py2neo

I use scrapy in order to scrape a social network and then get the data in a NEO4J database.

My challenge here is to relate 2 items each other:

```
class person(scrapy.Item):
name=Field()

class AnotherPerson(scrapy.Item):
name=Field()
```

I want to save those two items in my graph database by saying:

Person has relationship with AnotherPerson()

What I need here is to send two items in ONE pipeline !! How can we do this ?
I tried to send it through a list, but scrapy doesn't accept the list as soon as a collection is in there.

Here is my pseudo code:

1. I get a list of person (each person has profile and a list of firends like facebook)
2. For each person in this list:

   - I open his profile (through a request and send the response to a
     callback)
   - I take the response and create a item: Person() and fill it
   - I send the item with a "yield"
   - Then I open his list of friend (through a request and send the
     response to a another callback)
   - I have the friend list page
   - Then For each friend in this list (the page display a name and a
     city):
   - create an item: AnotherPerson()
   - I fill this item with the name and the city
   - I send the item with a "yield"

I have two pipelines. They work well to save the data in database, but I don't have any clue to how I can relate them because for that I need to do that in the same process (ie. pipeline).

I'm not sure if I've been clear, so don't hesitate to ask for clarifications.

Answer (score 2):

what about adding the `Person` item as a field for the `AnotherPerson`?. Remember you could always use the `meta` parameter on the requests to pass information between callbacks.

You could do something like:

```
parse_person(self, response):
    ...
    yield Request(self, url=someurl, callback=parse_anotherperson, 
                    meta={"some_key":"some_person_id"})
```

Then you could add a reference to the previous `Person` on your `AnotherPerson` item as a field or something else.